# How to route a single web2py application with the shortest possible URL without losing the admin application

Tags: python, web-applications, routes, web2py

I have a web2py website that has two applications: the standard admin application and a custom 'myapp' application.  For the sake of discussion we will say that the website lives at 'sub.projdomain.com'. I have been trying for hours to wrap my head around routes and python regular expressions, but I cannot seem to nail the functionality I desire.  I am attempting to replicate the following behavior:

```
URL in address bar               Effective URL
------------------               -------------
sub.projdomain.com               sub.projdomain.com/myapp/default/index
sub.projdomain.com/              sub.projdomain.com/myapp/default/index
sub.projdomain.com/foo           sub.projdomain.com/myapp/foo/index
sub.projdomain.com/foo?p=1       sub.projdomain.com/myapp/foo/index?p=1
sub.projdomain.com/foo/?p=2      sub.projdomain.com/myapp/foo/index?p=2
sub.projdomain.com/foo/bar?p=3   sub.projdomain.com/myapp/foo/bar?p=3
sub.projdomain.com/foo/bar/?p=4  sub.projdomain.com/myapp/foo/bar?p=4
sub.projdomain.com/a             sub.projdomain.com/admin/default/site
```

I always seem to have the problem where I call URL('login') or URL('/login') from the page "sub.projdomain.com/foo/bar/" and get a bad URL of the form "sub.projdomain.com/foo/login/" or something similar.  Currently I am setting the 'routes_in' and 'routes_out' tuples because I couldn't get it working with 'routers'.  I feel like I am overlooking what should be a very simple set of routes.  Am I overthinking the problem?

---- UPDATE ----

Alright, I think I managed to figure out a set of routes to get the behavior I want, but I would really like to know if this is the correct way to accomplish it.

```
routes_in = (
    #Map the default index to '/'
    ('/', '/myapp/default/index'),
    #Allow the admin application to be accessed
    ('/a', '/admin/default/index'),
    ('/a/$anything', '/admin/$anything'),
    #Re-wire actions as controllers unless the controller is also specified
    ('/$controller', '/myapp/$controller/index'),
    ('/$controller/', '/myapp/$controller/index'),
    ('/$controller/$action', '/myapp/$controller/$action'),
    #Map static access to our app
    ('/static/$anything', '/myapp/static/$anything'),
)
routes_out = [(x, y) for (y, x) in routes_in]
```

This setup requires that I carefully construct the parameters that I pass to URL(..).  I would like it to be easier to predict what URL(..) produces, but I doubt it gets any simpler than this... any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I figured this out.  I have yet to come across a case whereby URL() fails to generate the correct string.  I believe that this could be simplified further, but here it goes:

```
routes_in = (
    #Map the default index to '/'
    ('/', '/myapp/default/index'),
    #Allow the admin application to be accessed
    ('/a', '/a/default/index'),
    ('/a/$anything', '/a/$anything'),
    #Re-wire actions as controllers unless the controller is also specified
    ('/$controller', '/myapp/$controller/index'),
    ('/$controller/', '/myapp/$controller/index'),
    ('/$controller/$action', '/myapp/$controller/$action'),
    #Map static access to our application
    ('/static/$anything', '/myapp/static/$anything'),
)
#Reverse only some of the mappings so that URL() works correctly
routes_out = (
    ('/myapp/default/index', '/'),
    ('/a/$anything', '/a/$anything'),
    ('/myapp/$controller/index', '/$controller'),
    ('/myapp/$controller/$action', '/$controller/$action'),
    ('/myapp/static/$anything', '/static/$anything'),
)
```

I renamed the 'admin' application to 'a'.  Anytime I call URL() I must pass explicitly 2 parameters.  The first parameter is always the name of the controller, and the second parameter is always the name of the action following by any GET request variables.  E.g. `URL('default', 'index')` for the main index page or `URL('foo', 'bar?param=3')` for action `bar` in `foo` with `param` specified. However, `URL('foo', '?indexParam=test')`, is not allowed since `index` is not specified before the variable in the second parameter.  As long as I follow these rules everything seems to work consistently.

I am open to any other suggestions, but this is my accepted answer.  I hope this helps someone else going through the same dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve roughly the same outcome using the [parameter-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Parameter-based-system):

```
routers = dict(
    BASE=dict(
        default_application='myapp',
        default_controller='default',
        default_function='index',
        functions=dict(
            default=['list', 'of', 'functions', 'in', 'default.py'],
            foo=['list', 'of', 'functions', 'in', 'foo.py']
        )
    ),
    admin=dict(
        default_function='site',
        functions=['list', 'of', 'functions', 'in', 'default.py']
    )
)
```

The only difference is the "admin" app will still require "admin" in the URL (though I suppose you could try changing the name of the app itself by renaming its folder to "a").

Note, you only need to list the `functions` in the controllers if you want to remove "index" (or "site" in the case of admin) when the URL has additional args appended to it (the router needs to be able to distinguish between URL args and controller functions).

Comment: With your method I will have to explicitly declare each action of a controller in two places, wont I?  This means that if controller `foo` has actions `bar` and `tan`, that not only do I have to define functions for those actions in the controller, but I also have to specify them in my routes, right?  So, essentially I will have to reload the routes anytime that I add a new controller or a new action.  If that is true, then this solution requires that I break the DRY methodology when it could be avoided.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you only need to worry about listing the functions if you have URLs for the `index` function that also include additional args. Also, I suppose you could write a function that parses the controller file and extracts the list of functions automatically (routes.py is just a Python file, so you can run whatever Python code you like to generate the `routes` dictionary object).